# document click event not working on a specific image slider div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

here is the site I am working on:
https://cutt.ly/sxOSOTY
the problem is if you click on the image slider it doesn't detect the click event "On mobile devices only". On desktop its working. But seems like click on mobile device for that particular div is not working.

```html
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('clicked');
        });
```

Its working for full page, but not inside this div "slick-list draggable" I am unsure what is preventing click even. Any help is greatly Appriciated!

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: If your event handler is not invoked, check if it's attached to right HTML element. Check the rendered page from your browser console Inspector; it shows all the events attached to the element (at least in FF). That should give you a good understanding if the event handler is listening or not. Finally, check the console to see if there are any errors that are resulted when the event handler runs.

Comment: `touchMove:true` is slick slider property Please see option in https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Thanks @Hardik's yes it seems to be "touchend" property which is preventing click event.

Comment: @AbrarHossain perfect it took me directly to the correct direction. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
$('elemnt').unbind('touchend');
```

This resolved the issues. Now the div is clickable again.